# Reserve fixed storage for my android app

Tags: android, file, xamarin.android

Is it possible to reserve a fixed amount of storage space for my app. My app does check for the required free storage when it launches but that free storage is available to all apps and they can use it up anytime. I want to to reserve that space for my app alone. Does the android API allow for any such functionality? Are there other means of doing this? Is this even a good idea?

Comment: Are you referring to file system storage? I doubt the Android SDK has any way to reserve that. You could always write 0s into however much space you need, then use it as needed. I'm guessing it's not really a good idea though. What do you need to accomplish?

Comment: @dylansturg I want to save files in that fixed storage

Comment: But why do you need to reserve this storage space? Why are your files more important than everything else on this user's device?

Comment: @dylansturg This app will only be used by the company employees on their company phone. These phones also have whatsapp and other space consuming apps. That's why space needs to be reserved for this app since it is more important than anything else.

Comment: That's perfectly reasonable. I'm guessing your only option will be to write enough files with sufficient size to reserve that space (fill it up with 0s or whatever), and then rewrite your real content into the files as you get it. If you're using the space with files already, then other apps can't use it. There might be something in the SDK that I'm not aware of though.

Comment: @AliZahid did find solution for your question? if you found would you share it here.

Comment: @AliZahid how was your solution?  Let us know